# Write heavy elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing a real time analytics tool using kafka,storm and elasticsearch and want a elasticsearch that is write optimized for about 50K/sec inserts. For the purpose of POC I tried inserting bulk documents into the elasticsearch attaining 10K inserts per seconds.

I am running ES on a large box of amazon ec2.
I have tweaked the properties as below:

```
indices.memory.index_buffer_size: 30%
indices.memory.min_shard_index_buffer_size: 30mb
indices.memory.min_index_buffer_size: 96mb

threadpool.bulk.type: fixed
threadpool.bulk.size: 100
threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 2000


bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

But I want write performance in order of 50Ks and not 10Ks to ensure the normal flow of my storm topology. Can anyone suggest how to configure a heavy write optimized ES cluster.

Comment: I don't think that there is "the answer" for you here. You will have to measure and optimize your settings. Google will probably help with some default settings.

Answer (score 1):

The [scripts](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/?wpdmact=process&did=My5ob3RsaW5r) located here may help you improve indexing performance. There are many options and configurations to try, I write about some [here](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/elasticsearch-swap-index-type-application-job/) however this isn't a comprehensive list. Reducing replicas and increasing shards increases indexing performance but however reduces availability and searching performance during indexing.

Perhaps sending HTTP bulk requests to several nodes rather than just the master node could help you get the figures you desire.

Hope this helps somewhat. 10k/ps inserts is good better than what most people have achieved however whether they get to use a large Amazon instance I don't know.

Comment: FYI, those links give 403s

Comment: @AndrewWhite currently working on blog migration, update ASAP.